# Laravel scheduler to charge users recurring payments via peach payment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a project that uses Ionic and Laravel as a backend. The user uses our app based on monthly or annual subscriptions. So far I have been successful in implementing the initial charge of the subscriptions via peach payment.

So now I want every month end to charge the recurring monthly or annual subscriptions.

The idea I have is as follow:

1. Run Scheduler to check subscriptions table for all monthly active users where the expiry date is month-end (31/12/2020) or is the current month.
2. Generate transactions for all those users and save them to the billing table ( this is to get transaction_id to send to a payment gateway).
3. Run the scheduler using the billing info where created_at is today, send each transaction to payment gateway api for processing.
4. On Api response get status of each payment request and save/update the db billing table using transaction_id as primaryKey.
5. Update the subscriptions table (status, new expiry date) after the billing table is update

Any help or direction with this will be appreciated. The code below is the code to use for sending a single charge request.

```
/**
     * Monthly Subscriptions
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function chargeMonthlySubscription(Request $request)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        $url = "$this->url/registrations/$request->registrationId/payments";
        $data = "entityId=$this->entityId" .
            "&amount=$request->subscription_amount" .
            "&currency=ZAR" .
            "&customer.merchantCustomerId=$request->subscription_no" .
            "&customer.givenName=$request->first_name" .
            "&customer.surname=$request->last_name" .
            "&recurringType=$request->recurring_type" .
            "&paymentType=DB";

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "$url",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                $this->token,
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cron job that will run at the end of the month, first create a command:

```
php artisan make:command YourCommand
```

Your command would look like something else:

```
  <?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class YourCommand extends Command
{
    //Name that will be used to call command
    protected $signature = 'your:command';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        //Here you will handle all the logic. For ex:
        $record = App/Example::first();
        
        //Implement condition that will determine if the record will be updated
        $record->update();
    }
}
```

After that, inside App/Console/Kernel.php create the schedule for that command:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    //Name that you gave it in the protected $signature = 'your:command';
    $schedule->command('your:command')->monthly('23:30');
}
```

This way the command will be run monthly and you can do anything according to your business logic. You can read more about [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) & [commands](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan) on the official docs.